# How to Speed Up Heroku Deploy using Puppeteer buildpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

### Is possible to speed up heroku deploy speed using puppetter buildpack ?

#### It is taking so long to finish the build in every github's repo update, and seems that each time the chrome base is reinstalled, something like that...

#### Can someone help me please ?

[image]

[image]